# How to add admin custom module page (Button) in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, uicomponent, labels

Here I already created the button

```
if ($this->_isAllowedAction('custom_Mpquotesystem::mpquotes')) {
            $this->buttonList->update(
                'delete',
                'label',
                __('Delete Quote')
            );

        } else {
            $this->buttonList->remove('delete');
        }
```

When I am changing the label name it works

> But when I copied this code to the other place and changed the button_id it is not working.
>   and also I want to know how this works

Comment: Where you have copied and on which module you have copied? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: custom module in magento admin

Comment: they already added block/edit/edit.php

with my question code 

i copied to below the line pasted but not showing any button

Comment: Check this if ($this->_isAllowedAction('custom_Mpquotesystem::mpquotes')) code. I think its not allowed.

Comment: hoooo..................

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122236/73525   this answer i tried but

when i click on this the delete   the record is deleting .(i didn't want this) 
how i can change to my custom logic